# Apache's Velocity — getTemplate() . how to pass string/object instead of .VM file

Tags: java, velocity

Apache's Velocity — getTemplate(). Actually its allowing to pass the .vm file name , can i pass the string/object here? is there any method available to pass the string/object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use String as Velocity Template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432468/how-to-use-string-as-velocity-template)

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample code that is working for me.
Velocity version: 1.7
I use log4j as a logger.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader;
import org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.util.StringResourceRepository;


private static void velocityWithStringTemplateExample() {
    // Initialize the engine.
    VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
    engine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
    engine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", LOGGER.getName());
    engine.setProperty(Velocity.RESOURCE_LOADER, "string");
    engine.addProperty("string.resource.loader.class", StringResourceLoader.class.getName());
    engine.addProperty("string.resource.loader.repository.static", "false");
    //  engine.addProperty("string.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", "1");
    engine.init();

    // Initialize my template repository. You can replace the "Hello $w" with your String.
    StringResourceRepository repo = (StringResourceRepository) engine.getApplicationAttribute(StringResourceLoader.REPOSITORY_NAME_DEFAULT);
    repo.putStringResource("woogie2", "Hello $w");

    // Set parameters for my template.
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("w", "world!");

    // Get and merge the template with my parameters.
    Template template = engine.getTemplate("woogie2");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    template.merge(context, writer);

    // Show the result.
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
}
```

Comment: can we use class resource loader with String resource loader, both together?

Answer (score 2):

I searched for hours on the same question, finally found the unit test code that shows everything necessary.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/velocity/engine/trunk/velocity-engine-core/src/test/java/org/apache/velocity/test/StringResourceLoaderRepositoryTestCase.java

Comment: Tried all tests, and all have failed with Velocity 1.7!

Answer (score 1):

look into the StringResourceLoader

Comment: I found one example for StringResourceLoader. http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/StringResourceLoader.html  . But we are having our template info in string formate. we need to pass the string instead of .vm. what should i do for this scenario. please if there is any example code.

Comment: The StringResourceLoader allows you to directly add templates to your repository and then retrieve them like any other template.  StringResourceLoader.getRepository().putStringResource(myTemplateName, myTemplateString);

Comment: `StringResourceLoader.getRepository()` returns null. Is there any property to set?

Comment: Been a long time. Probably should configure a VelocityEngine to use it and initialize the engine first with properties like these:
resource.loader = string

string.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader