# Velocity String Template Loading at startup

Tags: java, velocity

I have a list of strings in the memory. I want to load all of them as velocity templates during the application startup. How do I do it ?

I know how to create template from a string from here: [How to use String as Velocity Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432468/how-to-use-string-as-velocity-template)

But I want to know how to load all template strings in one shot

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the collection of strings and initialize them all--not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: I have 2 questions
1. I am not sure which piece of the code mentioned in that link exactly initializes the template. DO i have to create a new template everytime and call `template.initDocument();` to initialize the template ? or is calling `runtimeServices.parse(reader, "Template name"));` sufficient ?
2. After loading, how do I fetch a particular template ? IS it like `velocityEngine.getTemplate("Template name")`

Comment: You'd need to keep references to the compiled templates. IIRC `getTemplate` is for retrieving templates using normal template resource management (classpath, filesystem, etc.) The code chunk shown is what initializes the template, although I don't know if it's *all* necessary, or if there are shorter ways. Not really sure what you're trying to do, so it's difficult to provide advice beyond the specific question you're asking--right now it sounds to me like you're doing it wrong, though :)

Comment: In freemarker, I can initialize a StringTemplateLoader and add all my templates there. And later I can access the cached templates by their name. I was hoping to find something similar in velocity but seems otherwise :(

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. FreeMarker has better error reporting, too.