# Velocity template as a String in Java

Tags: java, string, velocity, velocity-template-language

I have a java String which is basically a velocity template.

```
String vt = "#foreach ($number in [1..34])  $number += $number  #end"
String result = *String_vt_calculated_by_Velocity_Engine*;
System.out.println(result);
```

How can I evaluate the above String in Java and get the result?

Comment: You've already stated that it is a _Velocity_ template, so feed that string to Velocity and get the result back. How to do that should be coveredy by the Velocity documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Velocity.Evaluate` check this [Document](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/developer-guide.html#the-velocity-helper-class)

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
public class LoadTemplateFromStringTest {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
       VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

       StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      String vt = "#foreach ($number in [1..34])  $number += $number  #end";
        Velocity.evaluate( context, sw, "", vt);
        System.out.println(sw);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to `Velocity.evaluate()` (see `org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity` in the [API](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/Velocity.html)).